# join scrambles output

Tags: join

For some reason my output of join is strange and scrambled; here is the command I use:

```
join -t, -j 1 -o1.1,2.2,1.2  f1 f2
```

Where f1:

```
1,87
```

and f2:

```
1,337
```

The output is:

```
,8737
```

and I am at loss as to why the output of join is not as expected. I have checked my locale already, with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the file have DOS line endings (CR LF)? Add the output of `join -t, -j 1 -o1.1,2.2,1.2  f1 f2 | od -c` please.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know the `od` command ! Your intuition was right, it is DOS endings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data file are DOS text files.  Each line has a trailing carriage return character.

The output that you expect is

```
1,337,87
```

but since there is a carriage return after the `7` in `337` (from the DOS line-ending in the second file), the cursor moves back to the start of the line before printing `,87`, overwriting `1,33` there.

Run `dos2unix` on the data files to convert them to Unix text files, or instruct whatever program that creates them to create Unix text files.

Comment: Thanks, indeed this is it. I suspected it at first but threw that idea of since the files were made by a colleague on MacOS, it it seems the python csv module output DOS files by default